# Excel does not show correct time in cells

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

In my WPF application I receive a .txt file, parse it, and print all the analysis to an Excel file. I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. The problem is, that when there is time in cells, the cell shows `40:51.3`, but when I click on it, the formula bar shows `11:40:51 AM`. I need the cell to also display 11:40:51 AM. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: The issue, you describe, is a number format issue. Your Excel cell seems to have the number format `mm:ss.0`. It should have `hh:mm:ss AM/PM`. How do your program fills this cell? Code please ;-).

Comment: well, there is a lot of code there, but the sequence is: I catch the line containing the time, as a string (11:32:30.31621, for example), then place it in a DataTable, filter it as needed, and then place it in the initiated excel file, `newSheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum] = rawDataDT.Rows[rowNumber][colNumber].ToString();` where newSheet is `Worksheet newSheet = (Worksheet)sheets.Add(sheets[sheetNumber], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);`  @AxelRichter

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the relevant code there. Comments are not the right place for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something puts `11:32:30.31621` (time with parts of seconds) into a Excel cell, then Excel uses the number format `mm:ss.0` per default. To avoid this, you have to set the number format for this cell explicit.

Pseudo code:

If the content of the rawDataDT is time, then:

```
...
newSheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum].NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM";
newSheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum] = rawDataDT.Rows[rowNumber][colNumber].ToString();
...
```

end of IF block.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Can I apply this format for the whole table? so that all the appearances of time in the table will have this format, not depending on specific cells?

Comment: As far as I know, no. But are the parts of the seconds really needed? If not, you could only put the part "11:32:30" into the Excel cell. For such inputs the locale default time number format is used.